# Image cut off between two pages when export pdf using jspdf

Tags: reactjs, sharepoint-online, jspdf, html2canvas, spfx

I have created SPFx react functional component for export PDF.

I have used JSPDF for export pdf. When I tried to export the PDF images are cut off between two pages. Please refer to the below screenshot for better understanding.
[image]

Below is my code snippet.

```
const exportToPdf = () => {
    ref.current.style.display = 'block';
    let pdf = new JSpdf('p', 'pt', 'a4', true);
    let pWidth = pdf.internal.pageSize.width; // 595.28 is the width of a4
    let srcWidth = document.getElementById('toRender').scrollWidth;
    let margin = 20; // narrow margin - 1.27 cm (36);
    let scale = (pWidth - margin * 2) / srcWidth;
    pdf.html(document.getElementById('toRender'), {
        x: margin,
        y: margin,
        autoPaging: 'text',
        margin: [10, 0, 10, 0],
        html2canvas: {
            scale: scale,
        },
        callback: function () {
            pdf.save("Demo.pdf");
            ref.current.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
}
```

Can anyone help me with the same?

Comment: Kindly note that I am not a designer and this is not a design issue pdf content is dynamically increased or decreased. So image cut-off issue occurs and I need to fix that.